# Change validation requirements in contact form

Tags: javascript

What to change in the code below (.js from contact form) so that "nazwisko" field is not a required field? This is one file from .php contact form. I was checking some options but I`m not so familiar with .js. Is it enough to just erase this "nazwisko" line from the code or should I just put "false" next to the requirements?
Thank you for your support!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

/***************************************/
/* Form validation */
/***************************************/
$( '#j-forms' ).validate({

    /* @validation states + elements */
    errorClass: 'error-view',
    validClass: 'success-view',
    errorElement: 'span',
    onkeyup: false,
    onclick: false,

    /* @validation rules */
    rules: {
        nazwisko: {
            required: true
        },
        dataur: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        'imiona-rodzice': {
            required: true
        },
        telefon: {
            required: true
        },
        klasa: {
            required: true
        },
        szkola: {
            required: true
        },
        adres: {
            required: true
        },
        telkur: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        nazwisko: {
            required: 'Podaj swoje Imię i Nazwisko'
        },
        dataur: {
            required: 'Podaj swoją datę urodzenia'
        },
        'imiona-rodzice': {
            required: 'Podaj imiona rodziców'
        },
        telefon: {
            required: 'Podaj telefon do rodziców'
        },
        klasa: {
            required: 'Podaj swoją klasę'
        },
        szkola: {
            required: 'Podaj swoją szkołę'
        },
        adres: {
            required: 'Podaj swój adres'
        },
        telkur: {
            required: 'Podaj swój telefon'
        },
        email: {
            required: 'Podaj adres email',
            email: 'Niepoprawny format'
        },

    },
    // Add class 'error-view'
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).closest('.input').removeClass(validClass).addClass(errorClass);
        if ( $(element).is(':checkbox') || $(element).is(':radio') ) {
            $(element).closest('.check').removeClass(validClass).addClass(errorClass);
        }
    },
    // Add class 'success-view'
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).closest('.input').removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        if ( $(element).is(':checkbox') || $(element).is(':radio') ) {
            $(element).closest('.check').removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        }
    },
    // Error placement
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if ( $(element).is(':checkbox') || $(element).is(':radio') ) {
            $(element).closest('.check').append(error);
        } else {
            $(element).closest('.unit').append(error);
        }
    },
    // Submit the form
    submitHandler:function() {
        $( '#j-forms' ).ajaxSubmit({

            // Server response placement
            target:'#j-forms #response',

            // If error occurs
            error:function(xhr) {
                $('#j-forms #response').html('An error occured: ' + xhr.status + ' - ' + xhr.statusText);
            },

            // Before submiting the form
            beforeSubmit:function(){
                // Add class 'processing' to the submit button
                $('#j-forms button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true).addClass('processing');
            },

            // If success occurs
            success:function(){
                // Remove class 'processing'
                $('#j-forms button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false).removeClass('processing');

                // If response from the server is a 'success-message'
                if ( $('#j-forms .success-message').length ) {

                    // Remove classes 'error-view' and 'success-view'
                    $('#j-forms .input').removeClass('success-view error-view');
                    $('#j-forms .check').removeClass('success-view error-view');

                    // Reset form
                    $('#j-forms').resetForm();

                    // Prevent submitting the form while success message is shown
                    $('#j-forms button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);

                    setTimeout(function(){
                        // Delete success message after 5 seconds
                        $('#j-forms #response').removeClass('success-message').html('');

                        // Make submit button available
                        $('#j-forms button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false);
                    }, 5000);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
/***************************************/
/* end form validation */
/***************************************/
```

Comment: You want to make this field "nazwisko" as not required?

Comment: java!=javascript.. Also where is php?

Comment: Yes, I need to make "nazwisko" field as not required :)

Comment: Okay then just do this : nazwisko: {
       required: false
    }

Comment: Thanks, shall I also remove
nazwisko: {
            required: 'Podaj swoje Imię i Nazwisko'
        },
from messages part?

Comment: You can remove if you want.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this solution and it didn`t work :(

Comment: It works, sorry, I just had to change the browser/clear history...

Answer (score 0):

as @Amit said:
Only change this one line in rules section.
Not necessary to change or delete the message in message part itself.

```
/* @validation rules */
rules: {
    nazwisko: {
        required: false
    },
```

Comment: great to hear that @PiKej then you can mark your question as answered.